# Compare passwords

Tags: java, spring-security

I use this code with Spring password encrypt in order to compare password and confirmation password:

```
if(!passwordEncoder.encode(resetDTO.getPassword()).equals(passwordEncoder.encode(resetDTO.getConfirmPassword()))){
....
}
```

But always they are not matched when I send correct values. What is the correct way to compare hashed values?

Comment: Your `equals` method is wrong, or `encode` is wrong, or `getPassword` or `getConfirmPassword` or the input data is wrong.

Comment: @luk2302 what is the proper way to compare hashes?

Comment: hashes are strings, so `string1.equals(string2)`.

Comment: Why are you comparing the hashes in the first place when you have access to both the original values? You only need to compare with hashes when the hash is the only information you have. (Like when you fetch/compare it from the database.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to verify that a submitted password matches an encrypted (hashed) password you would use

```
passwordEncoder.matches(rawEnteredPassword, storedEncryptedPassword)
```

(assuming that `passwordEncoder` is a [Spring PasswordEncoder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.11.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/PasswordEncoder.html))

If you are however trying to verify that the password and the password confirmation are equal (if the user enters both passwords at the same time) you could just use

```
Objects.equals(resetDTO.getPassword(), resetDTO.getConfirmPassword())
```